# How to find calls to a method using Python introspection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I just found some test methods in a project which did not have the required "test_" prefix to ensure that they are actually run. It should be possible to avoid this with a bit of linting:

1. Find all `TestCase` assertion calls in the code base.
2. Look for a method with a name starting with "test_" in the call hierarchy.
3. If there is no such method, print an error message.

I'm wondering how to do the first two, which basically boil down to one problem: **how do I find *all* calls to a specific method in my code base?**

Grepping or other text searches won't do, because I need to introspect the results and find parent methods etc. until I either get to the test method or there are no more callers. I need to get a *reference* to the method to avoid matching methods which happen to have the same name as the ones I'm looking for.

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Use a version specific tag at your discretion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible approaches here.

1. Static approach:

   You could parse the code base using the ast module to identify all function calls and consistently store the origin and the target of the call. You would have to identify all classes and function definition to keep a track of the current context of each call. The limit here is that if you call instance methods, there is no simple way to identify what class the method actually belongs. Same if you use variables that refer to modules

   Here is a Visitor subclass that can read Python source files and build a dict {caller: callee}:

   ```
   class CallMapper(ast.NodeVisitor):
       def __init__(self):
           self.ctx = []
           self.funcs = []
           self.calls = collections.defaultdict(set)
       def process(self, filename):
           self.ctx = [('M', os.path.basename(filename)[:-3])]
           tree = ast.parse(open(filename).read(), filename)
           self.visit(tree)
           self.ctx.pop()
       def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
           print('ClassDef', node.name, node.lineno, self.ctx)
           self.ctx.append(('C', node.name))
           self.generic_visit(node)
           self.ctx.pop()
       def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
           print('FunctionDef', node.name, node.lineno, self.ctx)
           self.ctx.append(('F', node.name))
           self.funcs.append('.'.join([elt[1] for elt in self.ctx]))
           self.generic_visit(node)
           self.ctx.pop()
       def visit_Call(self, node):
           print('Call', vars(node.func), node.lineno, self.ctx)
           try:
               id = node.func.id
           except AttributeError:
               id = '*.' + node.func.attr
           self.calls['.'.join([elt[1] for elt in self.ctx])].add(id)
           self.generic_visit(node)
   ```
2. Dynamic approach:

   If you really want to identify what method is called, when more than one could share the same name, you will have to use a dynamic approach. You would decorate individual functions or all methods from a class in order to count how many times they were called, and optionnaly where they were called from. Then you would start the tests and examine what actually happened.

   Here is a function that will decorate all methods from a class so that the number all calls will be stored in a dictionnary:

   ```
   def tracemethods(cls, track):
       def tracker(func, track):
           def inner(*args, **kwargs):
               if func.__qualname__ in track:
                   track[func.__qualname__] += 1
               else:
                   track[func.__qualname__] = 1
               return func(*args, *kwargs)
           inner.__doc__ = func.__doc__
           inner.__signature__ = inspect.signature(func)
           return inner
       for name, func in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isfunction):
           setattr(cls, name, tracker(func, track))
   ```

   You could tweak that code to browse the interpretor stack to identify the caller for each call, but is is not very easy because you get the unqualified name of the caller function and will have to use the file name and line number to uniquely identify the caller.

Comment: I am trying to do *static* analysis, so I need to find out whether an assertion method is called *without* running the code. But the second approach does look interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a start. You will use a couple of standard libraries:

```
import dis
import inspect
```

Suppose you're interested in this source code: `myfolder/myfile.py`
Then do this:

```
import myfolder.myfile

def some_func():
    ''

loads = {'LOAD_GLOBAL', 'LOAD_ATTR'}
name_to_member = dict(inspect.getmembers(myfolder.myfile))
for name, member in name_to_member.items():
    if type(member) == type(some_func):
        print(name)
        for ins in dis.get_instructions(member):
            if ins.opname in loads:
                print(name, ins.opname, ins.argval)
```

Other fun things to do: run `dis.dis(member)`, or print out `dis.code_info(member)`.

This will let you visit each function defined in the file,
and visit each executable statement to see if it might be a method call you care about.
Then it's up to you to Do The Right Thing with potential test methods.

Comment: This seems to give me `Instruction` objects containing *strings,* but I don't really want to rely on string matching methods. Are these libraries capable of giving me a *reference* to the method being called?

Comment: Well, really that's the only sort of method description that python source _has_. Sure, there's the inconvenience of setting up all imports same as at runtime before calling `getmembers`, I'll grant you that. But once that is in place, you can do exactly what the interpreter does at runtime, looking up a LOAD_GLOBAL string in globals() or LOAD_ATTR in locals(). Take a look at e.g. `dir(globals()['__builtins__'])`. Holding such a reference, you can query `__file__`, `__name__`, and similar. For nitty gritty details see Allison Kaptur's amazing pure python article and implementation of Byterun.

Comment: Byterun is at http://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/a-python-interpreter-written-in-python.html